# WebApi Output Cache

Tags: asp.net-web-api, outputcache

I'm trying to implement an output cache in WebApi that can cache the responses already processed by filters and generate responses that are not processed by formatters.

From what I've seen ActionFilterAttribute's OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted are execute before the serialization formatters and so if you cache a response, at a cache hit you will respond the exact same content and that content will be serialized again to transmission.

As a possible solution in MVC I think that you can do this by implementing a IResultFilter that override OnResultExecuted by caching the serialized response. With this approach I don't know how to intercept the request handling to avoid the serialization formatters, I think that a possible solution to intercept is create a custom ActionResult to be handled directly by IResultFilter. Please note that this solution is not suitable for me because I'm implementing OutputCache in a WebApi application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing the response, formatters in Web API come into action for HttpContents of type `ObjectContent` only.

In you OnActionExecuted method, you could force the serialization to happen by doing something like below and then set the response content as `StreamContent` (this way the formatters wouldn't be coming into picture):

An example below:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = actionExecutedContext.Response;

    if (response != null && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        ObjectContent originalContent = response.Content as ObjectContent;

        if (originalContent != null)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            // NOTE:
            // 1. We are forcing serialization to occur into a buffered stream here
            // 2. This can cause exception. You can leave it as it is and Web API's exception handling mechanism should
            //    do the right thing.
            originalContent.CopyToAsync(ms).Wait();

            // reset the position
            ms.Position = 0;

            StreamContent newContent = new StreamContent(ms);

            // Copy the headers
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> header in originalContent.Headers)
            {
                newContent.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(header.Key, header.Value);
            }

            //dispose the original content
            originalContent.Dispose();

            //TODO: cache this new httpcontent 'newContent' (so we are caching both serialized body + headers too)

            //Set the response
            //NOTE: This newContent will not hit the formatters
            actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.Response.Content = newContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello I'm very grateful for your response but what if you generated a ByteArrayContent instead of a StreamContent, using the ReadAsByteArrayAsync?

Comment: Yes,even if you set the response to be a ByteArrayContent, the formatters wouldn't get involved...Can you elaborate more on what you meant by ReadAsByteArrayAsync? Here were talking about writing of the resposne, so I am not clear as to what you meant by "using ReadAsByteArrayAsync"?

Comment: What I mean is instead of using CopyToAsync to a memory stream you can get the byte[] of your response already formatted and store them. When you have a cache hit you can retrieve your cached formatted response bytes and create a ByteArrayContent to be the content of your cache hit response. Is there any disadvantage in using this strategy instead of yours, by this I mean the WebApi has any advantege using a StreamContent instead of a ByteArrayContent? Again very grateful for your help